# Codelength return from community_infomap of Igraph

Tags: python, igraph

I need to get the codelength of a community-network in Python.

The documentation (https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#community_infomap) says that community_infomap returns the calculated membership vector and the corresponding codelength in a tuple. But the output of

```
gm.community_infomap(edge_weights=gm.es['weight'], vertex_weights=None, trials=10)
```

where gm is my directed weighted network is just an <igraph.clustering.VertexClustering, that gives me the clusters and its elements but nothing about the codelength.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are looking at the documentation of GraphBase.community_infomap. Please check the documentation of Graph.community_infomap instead:

https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#community_infomap

It explains that `codelength` is an attribute of the returned object.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up everyone - I forgot to update the documentation on the site after the release of python-igraph 0.8.3, but now it's there: https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#community_infomap